# Qt: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Открываю проект, при запуске вылетает ошибки

> No such file or directory

,
но эти файлы у меня есть в проекте (смотри стрелки)
(путь файлов Qt написаны на английском)

[image: Изображения]

Comment: Если студия говорит что файла нет, значит она его не может найти. Проверяйте пути и наличие файлов.

Comment: покажите хоть один документ, где идет включение одного из этих файлов.

Comment: Внизу крякозябры. Очень похоже на проблемы с кодировкой. Попробуй переписать пути на латиницу.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста, вы попробовали предложенные решения? С ними, или без них, получилось решить задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно необходимо пересобрать свой проект и проверить файл конфигурации проекта .pro, что текущие файлы подключены к проекту корректно.

Comment: @DenisBubnov тут часто нельзя быть уверенным в стопроцентном решении вопроса, потому что автор не даёт полной информации. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я хотел отметить сообщение тревогой,  что это не ответ, а комментарий, но тут уже был один VoteUp